# Can MySql database server store date value in mm-dd-yyyy format?

Tags: mysql, date

Can MySql database server store date value in mm-dd-yyyy format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as a native `DATE` column: Those are always represented as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

However, you can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to output the date in any format you like.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column, "%m-%d-%Y");
```

Comment: thanks you are like family member to me :) (see you so often)

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as dates, not strings.
They are not stored in any specific format.

You can *retrieve* dates in a variety of formats by calling [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format client side like this:

```
mysql> set date_format = '%m-%d-%Y';
```

How the database actually stores the dates should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

No mysql cannot store date in that format.
It can store dates only in the yyyy-mm-dd format.
u change the format of the data to be inserted or extracted from the mysql db.